# Hide items from admins

Tags: content-editor, security, content-management, search-facet, editor-user-permissions

Is there any way to hide items in the content tree from admins? Only specific users would be visible. I already tried with the security editor etc..

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Sitecore as Administrator can access anything from content in Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible in Sitecore.

Admins have access rights for all the items.

You cannot disallow read or write access rights for them.

You should not make users administrators if they are not supposed to have access to something in the system. Instead, create new role with access to pretty much everything, end then remove access to what should be hidden.